# Lucene 5.0.0 LockObtainFailedException when running under multiple thread

Tags: java, lucene, apache-spark

I got LockObtainFailedException exception when running under multiple threads. The error was gone if it only ran under single thread.

```
  org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed out: NativeFSLock@/home/dic_new/indexfolder/write.lock.
```

Code fragment is pasted as follows.

```
    Path indexLoc = Paths.get(this.indexLoc);
    Directory fsDir = FSDirectory.open(indexLoc);
    if (!DirectoryReader.indexExists(fsDir)) {
        return null; //return if index not exist
    }

    //new text added in with append mode
    Directory fsDir = FSDirectory.open(indexLoc);
    IndexWriterConfig iwConf = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);
    iwConf.setOpenMode(IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.APPEND);
    IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(fsDir, iwConf);


    Document d = new Document();
    d.add(new TextField(this.fieldName, text, Store.NO));
    indexWriter.addDocument(d);

    indexWriter.commit();
    indexWriter.close();
```

P.s., I tried with FSDirectory.open(indexLoc, NoLockFactory.INSTANCE) but it doesn't work with multiple threads, as index corruption error message was generated.

Here, the concurrency is handled by Spark when setting spark.master to local[K].

Comment: pretty obvious, that some thread try to write into directory, while it's locked.

Comment: yes, but how to solve this problem? @Mysterion

Comment: im pretty sure it's not lucene problem, you need to fix what you're doing within Spark